# Solving a "multi-objective knapsack" puzzle

Tags: php, algorithm, math, optimization

So I have this mental puzzle that I have been trying to come up with a solution for using PHP; revolving the "Knapsack problem". I have done a fair bit of reading around it from the a decision theory point of view as well as computer science angle looking at how it would be implemented. What I have come to realise is that using "brute force" won't work.

So allow me to explain the predicament.

Lets say your body needs: **50g of glucose, 20g of carbohydrates, 5g of fibre and 120g of protein.**.

Your fridge has:

- 1 apple - (10g of glucose, 2g of carbohydrates, 0.5g of fibre and 1g of protein)
- 0.5 apple - (5g of glucose, 1g of carbohydrates, 0.25g of fibre and 0.5g of protein)
- 1 steak- (5g of glucose, 20g of carbohydrates, 5g of fibre and 50g of protein)

etc etc... with scope for going out and buying more stuff to be later added to the "fridge pool". In the grand scheme of things, this fridge pool might be a pre-defined array or a list of rows pulled from a table (which would be a lot more functional/practical).

Now, what I am trying to achieve is find the best/closest match from my "fridge pool" to match the requirements I need.

It doesn't have to be a 100% match (because that may will be impossible) but it needs to be the **closest mathematical match**.

How would I start solving a problem like this? I have seen some PHP classes out there that look at working with one variable and others that try and reach the maximal permutation, but in my case I want the closest one to the set requirements.

Thanks :)

*All of the above are hypothetical values and are used here for demo purposes.*

Comment: You can formulate this as a MIP (Mixed Integer Program). I believe the open source solver LpSolve has some PHP bindings.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen thanks for pointing me to that. I've had a look at LpSolve and it does have a PHP option, but I am not got going to lie, I fail to see how I can transpose the examples included on http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/PHP.htm for my problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MIP model that could be used to solve your problem:

[image]

LpSolve is designed to solve models like this. Note that this is not really very close to a knapsack problem.

Comment: Thank you @ErwinKalvelagen for that. I won't lie but that may have just went straight over my head. I will spend some time familiarising myself with LpSolve before looking at how to transpose this onto a practical solution. Thank you for your help though!